# Which action for triggering cron "wp"or "init"?

Tags: plugin-development, actions, wp-cron

Which one do you recommend using within a plugin and why?

```
add_action( 'wp', 'trigger_me' );
function trigger_me() {

    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_plugin_cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_plugin_cron');
    }

}
```

**OR**

```
add_action( 'init', 'trigger_me' );
function trigger_me() {

    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_plugin_cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_plugin_cron');
    }

}
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of "wp" over "init" when registering/triggering cron function within a plugin?

Comment: Using cron aside, plugins should generally hook to the `init` hook. `wp` is used more internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'trigger_me' );

function trigger_me() {

    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_plugin_cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_plugin_cron');
    }

}
```

Why parse code on every request when you don't need to?

Comment: +1 Might seem small, but a few of these can add up quick.

Comment: Should probably also unschedule it on deactivation, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unschedule_event

Comment: While this is a correct "design" for adding cron in WP, it still have problem in some cases like: updating plugin version (trigger doesn't happen because the plugin has been activated), or in development stage when you modify the plugin code. Using `init` or `wp` hook may not be the "right" approach, but it solves these problems.

Comment: Plugins are deactivated/reactivated on update through admin. The fact that a plugin is in development is no excuse for poor coding.

Comment: This is correct answer, but what about using inside theme ?